# Archimedean absolute value on the set of real rational fractions, whose induced absolute value in $\mathbb{R}$ is the trivial one.

Tags: abstract-algebra, absolute-value

> Archimedean  absolute value on the set of real rational fractions, whose induced absolute value in $\mathbb{R}$ is the trivial one.

Can this be done?

So, my idea is to see it in $\mathbb{C}(t)$ so I can have my "irreducibles" easy to classify (i.e ($x-a$)).

So the absolute value must map:

$0 \to 0$

$k \neq 0, \,\,   k \to 1$ (This is to make the absolute value trivial when restricted to $\mathbb{C}$)

$(x-a)\to x_a \in \mathbb{R_+}$.

$\frac{1}{(x-a)}\to \frac{1}{x_a}$ (same $x_a$ as above)

Now, we can easily force the property $\mid \, p\cdot q\mid = \mid p \mid \cdot \mid q \, \mid $ when defining the absolute value on the remaining elements of $\mathbb{C}(t)$ in a trivial manner.

So, your absolute value should map:

$ k\cdot \frac{(x-a_1)...(x-a_n)}{(x-b_1)...(x-b_m)} \to \frac{x_{a_1}....x_{a_n}}{x_{b_1}...x_{b_n}}$

And its easy to check that its well defined.

The problem arises when securing the triangle inequality (and also making the absolute value archimidean)

Because there is no way (at least to my knowledge) of "factorizing" a sum of rational functions. So there is no way to predict where will $\mid \frac{p_1}{q_1} + \frac{p_2}{q_2} \mid$ will land.

The other way around this is forcing the triangle inequality in the definition and then securing the multiplicativeness, but I see it as a dead-end also.

The hard part is making it  so that it is the trivial absolute value when restricted to $\mathbb{C}$, because I have already come up with an example of an archimidean absolute value in $\mathbb{R(t)}$

My gut tells me this is impossible, but if anyone has any hints or ideas as to find an absolute value or to prove that it is impossible I would be very thankful.

Comment: how could the absolute value be archimedean if $|n|=1$ for every positive integer?

Comment: @user8268 maybe its trivial, but why can it not?

Comment: an absolute value is archimedean iff $|n|>1$ for some integer $n$

Comment: @user8268 by definition? Or is that a statement that can be proven? Because if that is your definition, I'm using a different one where an absolute value is non-archimidean if $\mid x + y \mid \leq max\{ \mid x \mid , \mid y \mid  \}$ and its archimidean if its not non-archimidean.

Comment: not by definition; you should find this result in any textbook talking about absolute values (sorry for not giving you a particular reference; the main idea of the proof of to look at $|(x+y)^n|$ with $n$ going to infinity)

Comment: spelling is archim**E**dean, not archimidean.

Comment: Under your definition, with $|1|=1$ (which can be done by scaling) we have that in a non-archimedean absolute value, $|2|=|1+1|\leq 1$ and inductively $|n+1|\leq \max\{|n|,1\}=1$. So if $|n|\gt 1$ for some integer $n$, then it is archimedean.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin that doesn't make it a non-archimedean absolute value, because you're only proving that it is restricted to $\mathbb{R}$. But how are you guaranteeing that $\mid P + Q \mid \leq max\{ \mid P \mid , \mid Q \mid  \}$ for any rational functions $P,Q$? See by finding any two rational functions that do not fulfill that inequality it is already archemedean, no matter if its non-archemedean restricted to the field. Remember I am defining it in $\mathbb{Q}(t)$

Comment: Your comment misses the point. What I said was that under the definition you give, one of the implications from user8268 follows easily: if $|n|\gt |1|$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ then the absolute value is necessarily archimedean. Nothing you write has **anything** to do with that.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, I think it is you that is missing the point, have you read the question? it all started with user8268 implying that it cannot be possible for an absolute value to be archimedean if $\mid n \mid = 1$ for positive integers, hence his comment: "an absolute value is archimedean IFF $\mid n \mid>1$
 for some integer n". You're whole comment is irrelevant to my question then.

Comment: Sigh. Yes, I read the question. Just because you don't want to hear doesn't mean what you are being told is irrelevant. user8268 gave you a charactetization of archimedean absolute values. You replied asking if it was a definition or a consequence and then gave the definition you were using. I proved, using *your* definition, half of the bi-implication user8268 gave, thereby answering part of the question you asked in comments. Not irrelevant. You proceeded to completely misunderstand what I wrote and complain about it because it wasn't what you thought it was/should be. That's silly.